# Social Tables Floor-Elements API function returns an empty array even though equipment has been added

Tags: social-tables

Event ID 3977534 has a table, chairs and projector. I try to retrieve the objects using the following URL:

https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/legacyvm3/teams/49992/events/3977534/elements

This returns an empty array. Why is that?

Strangely, the following URL does return data:

https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/legacyvm3/teams/49992/events/2069693/elements

even though event 2069693 has been deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for using our API.

We currently have two versions of our app running which has two different shapes of data for tables and chairs.

Anything you find in our docs containing "legacyvm3" in the route in general refers to the older version of our app. For the new events, to find table and chair information you want the /4.0/diagrams routes.

Comment: I have managed to retrieve the objects using /4.0/diagrams/{id} where I have obtained the value of {id} from the URL of the editor. I have not managed to figure out how to obtain this value from the API. I have tried /4.0/diagrams?event=3977534 but that returns an empty array. Please can you advise how to obtain the diagram id for a given event id.

Comment: Success! First I used /4.0/events-by-legacy-id/3977534 to obtain the new id for the event. Then I used /4.0/diagrams?event=54f45550-4644-11e9-8ef8-dd1db63e3e82 to obtain the floor elements.

Comment: Furthermore, I have found that /4.0/events/3977534 returns the same as  /4.0/events-by-legacy-id/3977534